React слишком много функций обновления состояния в родительском компоненте, вложенность компонентов
У меня родительский компонент хранит основные данные, каждый дочерний элемент-компонент в свою очередь имеет точно такие-же дочерние компоненты-элементы, и все они должны иметь функции createElement, UpdateElement, deleteElement. Т.к. данные о них хранятся в родительском компоненте в виде: {id: 0, name: "childComponent", childs: [{id: 0, name: "subchildComponent", childs [..]}]}  мне приходится писать логику этих функций там где этот объект что очень захламляет и не логично. Что в таком случае делать? Просто обрабатывать изменения всех вложенных объектов в родительском?
P.S. я создаю на основе данных выше Компонент ChildComponent у которого есть функции createElement, updateElement, deleteElement. В свою очередь я рендерю в этом элементе SubchildComponent компонент у которого в свою очередь рендеряться свои элементы и которые тоже должны обновляться.

Только что родилась идея возможного действия, создать состояние в SubchildComponent и записывать туда изменения subsubchuldCoponents, сделать useEffect и при изменении состояния вызывать handleChangeChilds с передачей нового массива !?
